# Change clustered index without dropping the primary key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, primary-key, full-text-search, clustered-index

In the past, I have chosen the `datetime` column *created* as inappropriate clustered index in the table.

Now I concluded (base on the execution plan) that it would be better to choose the ID *identity* primary key as the clustered key, because it is referenced as foreign key very often.

I would like to drop the current clustered key and create a new, but I cannot drop the primary key, because that the `full-text` index is dependent on that primary key.

Can I just switch primary key to clustered index or do I need to drop the primary key and the chain of all dependent objects?

Bellow you will find table definition and clustered index definition.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Realty](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    ....

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Realty] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
...


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Created] ON [dbo].[Realty]
(
    [Created] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop the existing clustered index, then create a new one on the `ID` column.

```
DROP INDEX [Created] ON dbo.Realty;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_Realty ON dbo.Realty (ID);
GO
```

Of course, you'll want to do this during a maintenance window so you don't cause too much blocking.  If you have Enterprise Edition you can do the CREATE INDEX operation online by adding `WITH (ONLINE=ON)` to the statement.

Comment: The one downside here is that the table will now be left with a clustered index on (ID) and another non-clustered index (the primary key) on (ID). While there could be situations where this (narrower) duplicate index is a good idea, I don't get the sense that it's what the OP really wants in this case.

Comment: Good point, @GeoffPatterson - I was working on a solution using `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to avoid the issue; however it will require making two copies of the data in the table to get around the `IDENTITY()` column.  I didn't want to propose a solution that is overly complex.